# Generating XML Serialization Assembly in Visual Studio 2012 does not work

Tags: .net, xml, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

In my Visual Studio 2012 Solution, I have a number of class libraries that have the **Properties --> Build --> Generate serialization assembly** set to **On**.

Yet when I build, no XML Serialization assemblies are built.

I have Googled this, and modified the `.csproj` of one of the projects to include the line

```
<SGenUseProxyTypes>false</SGenUseProxyTypes>
```

under the `<GenerateSerializationAssemblies>On</GenerateSerializationAssemblies>` element but that changed nothing.

**Platform Target** appears not to be relevant, because changing it again did not result in XML Serialization Assemblies being built.

Is this a known issue, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being that Visual Studio was installed without SGEN!

I worked around it temporarily by calling the version of SGEN.EXE in the Windows SDK.

Answer (score 5):

First make sure your project meets the SGen requirements. You can run the `GenerateSerializationAssemblies` target directly from the Command Prompt:

```
msbuild foo.csproj /t:GenerateSerializationAssemblies /v:detailed
```

Does it display this message?

> 'foo.dll' does not contain any types that can be serialized using
>   XmlSerializer. Please use /verbose switch for more information.

You may want to look into it if you believe that's an error. [Here's a good starting point](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/09/15/sgen-gives-assembly-does-not-contain-any-types-that-can-be-serialized-using-xmlserializer.aspx).